# Problems when Sleeping on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I'm not sure if asking a hardware specific question is right for superuser.com, but I have a problem with my Asus P5Q motherboard (or believe it's the hardware).

I do Start->Sleep my PC the computer and come back to it 3-4 hours later. By this time the processor fans have kicked into overdrive and the PC has effectively frozen and needs to be forced off by holding the power button down.

The Asus forums have been no help so I'm hoping I'll get a more intelligent response here. System spec is:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E8500, 3.16GHz
- Asus P5Q Deluxe (Socket 775)
- USB keyboard/mouse
- SATA raided drives

Comment: I have a P5Q Pro and have not experienced this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the answer is to turn off your keyboard + mouse from being able to wake the PC up. I've done this and it's been sleeping for the last two days like a log.